# Declaring a variable inside or outside a function

Tags: go

For example:

```
func internall(a string) int {
    someMap := map[string]int {
        "1" : 1,
        ...
        "1000000" : 1000000,
    }
    return someMap[a]
}
```

Or

```
var someMap = map[string]int {
    "1" : 1,
    ...
    "1000000" : 1000000,
}

func externall(a string) int {
    return someMap[a]
}
```

Question: If this function is called very often and multi-threaded, will there be an impact on optimization?
Where a variable is declared inside a function, will this result in the map being created multiple times?

Comment: if `someMap` is used by multiple functions, declare it outside of all functions. That makes it a global variable within that package.

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV It is used by one function, but this function is used very often.

Comment: If it's delcared inside the function, yes, it will be created on each call. It will be safe for concurrent use. If you only read the map, you may move it to package level, created once only, and can safely read it concurrently. If you also need to modify, then synchronization is needed to be concurrency-safe.

Comment: @icza 
That is, if I only read, declaring it outside the function is the best optimization?

Comment: Stop about this type of trivial optimisations unless you have factual evidence that this is a problem in your code.

Comment: Declaring it outside the function is dangerous unless you can _guarantee_ it will never ever be modified.  Unless you can prove with a profiler that this specific map allocation is a performance bottleneck, the "best optimization" is to use the safer allocation inside the function and avoid a lot of annoying and expensive developer time debugging the concurrency problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the map is large or the function is called very frequently, it's more efficient to declare the MAP as a `global variable (outside the function)`, not in the function.

**Why?**

When the MAP is declared `inside the function (in internal1) as a local variable`, it will be created and initialized every time the function is called. This can lead to overhead in terms of memory and processing time. This is a problem..

**Another way as a global variable:**

When the MAP is declared as a global variable, it will be created and initialized only once when the program starts. This means that all threads share the same instance. But be careful with synch. and race conditions. `sync.Map` from the Go standard library could be used for multithreading..